# How to load already computed confusion matrix to be used with the caret package in R

Tags: r, matrix, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have trained a Random Forest classifier (`randomForest` package) and it returns also the confusion matrix.

I want to compute sensitivity and specificity for each class, so I decided to load the confusion matrix with the `caret` package.
However I did not find how to load it. How can I achieve it?

Comment: there is a function in `caret` package called `confusionMatrix()`. Did you try that.
If `rf` contains your model,
`rf$pred` contains the results of predictions and their probabilities

`rf_cm <- rf$pred`
`confusionMatrix(rf_cm$pred, rf_cm$obs)` This would give you accuracy, Kappa, Sens Spec. etc.

Comment: Yes I tried that. This is the documentation of the package `randomForest`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf . If I understood correctly the documentation, the `randomForest` object does not contain neither the attribute `pred` nor the attribute `obs`

Comment: Ok so you need the confusion Matrix from `randomForest` package.

Comment: Nope, I got that using `rf$confusion`.. The problem is that, it does not provide the sensitivity and specificity for each class (I have 4 classes). I have to compute them on my own. Instead, the `caret` package handles it, but I cannot manage how to convert the matrix taken from `rf$confusion` to a suitable confusion matrix for the `caret` package.. I don't know if it's feasible.

Comment: Oh alright, so what is the `class()` of `rf$confusion`? and why don't you try running `rf` in caret with same `seed` and same input file. Because if the confusion matrix is same in both `randomForest` and `caret`'s `rf` method, then there is no question of loading. The running of rf method won't take much time in `caret`.

Comment: The class of `rf$confusion` is `matrix`. Unfortunately in my pipeline I have to use the `randomForest` package explicitly.

Comment: See if you can find any help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130053/roc-for-random-forest/31149340?noredirect=1#comment50311605_31149340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sowmya's comments, I achieve it by using the following code:

```
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(clf$predicted, labels)
```

where `clf` is the result of the execution of `randomForest()` call, while `labels` is the lists of reference labels of the output variable.